# Catch an error produced by pbsapply

Tags: r, multithreading

I have this code, where I copy and `untar` (using `gunzip`) a bunch of files into a directory on my harddisk using `pbsapply`:

```
library(pbapply)
library(parallel)
library(R.utils)

unpack <- function(x, exdir, remove, overwrite, skip){
  copy <- paste(exdir, tail(unlist(strsplit(x, "/")), 1), sep = "")
  file.copy(from = x, to = copy)
  x <- copy
  gunzip(as.character(x), remove = remove, overwrite = overwrite, skip = skip)
}

files <- as.matrix(dir(path.to.files, pattern = ".tar.gz"))

expath <- "C:/temp/

cl <- makeCluster(detectCores()-1)
clusterExport(cl, "unpack")
clusterExport(cl, "files")
clusterExport(cl, "expath")

pbsapply(cl = cl, t(files), FUN = function(x){
         unpack(x, exdir = expath, overwrite = FALSE, skip = TRUE, remove = TRUE)
       })
```

I use `gunzip` because I want to keep the .tar files and do not extract them.

In principle the code works just fine. However, at random points, I get the error:

> Error in checkForRemoteErrors: one node produced an error: No write permission for directory: C:/temp

I'm sure I have write permission.

Since this happens at random points, it's not reproducible.

My question now is, can I catch the error and just skip the file and continue processing?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Author of R.utils here: This could be because of a race condition where each worker is asserting that `C:/temp/` exists and it has write permissions to that folder.  If a worker finds that `C:/temp/` does not exists, it tries to create it.  Now, if multiple workers try to create it at the same time, you might have a race condition.

Try to make sure that `C:\temp\` really exists before launching the parallel code, e.g. `dir.create(expath)`.  Let me know if this makes a difference.

Also, in order to try to reproduce this, how big is `detectCores()` and roughly how many `tar.gz` files do you have?

BTW, the line

```
copy <- paste(exdir, tail(unlist(strsplit(x, "/")), 1), sep = "")
```

looks complicated.  AFAIU, `tail(unlist(strsplit(x, "/")), 1)` can be replaced by `basename(x)`, e.g. with `C:/a/b/c.tar.gz` you're getting `c.tar.gz`. Also, instead of using `paste()` to build your paths, use `file.path()`.  In other words, do something like:

```
copy <- file.path(exdir, basename(x))
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I tried creating the directory but it makes no difference. The problem exists if I use 2 to 12 cores. Using just one core works (it's not parallel then). I've got roughly 20000 `tar-gz` files, but the problem exists with much less (30 files) as well.
Thanks for the hint with `basename`, it's much clearer.